# Powershell - download image from a dynamic link

Tags: powershell, cognos

We have a server capacity reporting site that runs under Cognos.

The site has a logon for authentication. Then just input the server/hostname and you will be presented with the different links for the reports such as CPU/Memory & Disk utilizations.

The site produces an image/graph of the utilization. I want to be able to download/save the image.

So far what i have is below ..

```
## Initialize variables
$username = "TAUser1" 
$password = "Pas$W0rd" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$Folder = "D:\Data\Scripts\Cognos\Images\"

## Link to CPU Util
$Url1 = "https://XYZ..com:12345/tarf/servlet/dispatch?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2fpackage%5b%40name%3d%27Windows_OS_Reports%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27WI_NT_ProcessorTotal%27%5d&ui.name=WI_NT_ProcessorTotal&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=false&p_TCRDateFilter=<selectChoices><selectOption useValue=%22%20between cast( cast(_add_days(current_date,-30) as char(10) ) || ' 00:00:00.000' as TIMESTAMP) and cast( cast(   current_date  as char(10) )  || '23:59:59.999' as TIMESTAMP)%22 displayValue='Last 30 Days'/></selectChoices>&p_Param_Server=Primary:MyServer:NT"

## Open URL & Login 
$ie.navigate($Url1) 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 200} 
$ie.document.getElementById("CAMUsername").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("CAMPassword").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("cmdOK").Click()
start-sleep 20 
## -- after logon the image/chart of the CPU util is shown

## Get the link for the image/chart
$sources = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('img') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty src -Last 1

## The link looks something like this .. dynamic?
# >> https://XYZ..com:12345/tarf/servlet/dispatch?b_action=dc&f=b3V0cHV0MzMyMTQwMTY5NDExMzQ3OTE_&k=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-9uQyBEGBYwDFXnprWn6KQpc5Zig_&s=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-JbPEBnix8kFdZ2*-LnYbI3NszrU_&did=2013-03-21-08.24.10.711381

## I am able to go/navigate to this link, show me the image.
$ie.navigate($sources) 

## The image on that link ($sources) is the one i want to be able to download.
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success using PowerShell's built-in Invoke-WebRequest with its SessionVariable/WebSession flags for things like this.

Here is an example of how you might use it for your scenario.  I have not tested this as I do not have access to a Cognos server.  You may need to adapt it but the basics are here.

```
# This is needed for UrlEncode.
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | out-null

# These are the posted items. Expand if necessary. 
# You may need "cmdOk" = <something>;
$postItems = @{
    "CAMUsername" = $username;
    "CAMPassword" = $password;
}

# This builds the POST data for the login.
$encodedItems = $postItems.Keys | foreach { "$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_))=$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($postItems[$_]))" }
$body = $encodedItems -join "&"

# Passing SessionVariable lets us keep the requests under one "browser" session.
$mainPage = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable $session -Body $body -Method Post

# PowerShell's WebRequest provides a convenient Images array with all of the images.  Query this as necessary.
$imgSrc = $mainPage.Images | Select-Object -ExpandProperty src -Last 1    
$imgName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($p.Images[0].src)
$imgName += ".png" # Append the correct extension here!

# Finally, grab the img using the logged in session and write it out to a file as byte encoded. 
$outPath = Join-Path $Folder $imgName
Invoke-WebRequest $imgSrc -WebSession $session | Select -ExpandProperty Content | Set-Content -Encoding Byte $outPath
```

The magic is in passing `-SessionVariable $session` to the first request.  This kicks off a session as if you were using a browser so you can do things like logging in.  You pass this to future requests using `-WebSession $session`.

Depending on how the server's login feature works, you may need to kick off an earlier Invoke-WebRequest directly to the login page and then grab appropriate form items from there using the WebRequest Forms member.  For example, I've encountered pages that generate a serverside token that is expected to be passed in with the login credentials.  I'd suggest using your browser's developer tools to check exactly what is being posted and reproduce this using `$postItems`.

Comment: @Dylan thank you for looking into my question. I tried to adapt your suggestion.. 
i am getting an error below ..
    Set-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    At D:\Data\Scripts\Cognos\TCDB_7-2.ps1:31 char:110
    + ... -Encoding Byte $outPath
    +                    ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentC

Comment: @uNoKaWaL Take a look at my updated code.  I had left $outPath in the Set-Content empty as a placeholder for you to fill in with whatever you wanted to name the files.  I've updated this to use your $Folder variable with the file name from the URL to create $outPath.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that your URL doesn't include a filename extension for the image so you'll have to manually append one if you want one.  I've set it to .png in my example.  Change that to whatever the image actually is.

Comment: @Dylan the $imgSrc result gives me a parsed URL

<?b_action=dc&amp;f=b3V0cHV0MzMyMTQ4NTc4MDI2MzI2MTA_&amp;k=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-hHH4zZnTpCLtqVBxib4F09WKJAM_&amp;s=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-QrgF6CO4l*owSwzvuzgTNdf2khg_&amp;did=2013-03-21-08.24.10.711381>

the initial part is missing <https://XYZ..com:12345/tarf/servlet/dispatch>

Comment: These are the error messages i get when i continue >>
Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\Data\Scripts\Cognos\TCDB_7-2.ps1:27 char:1
+ $imgName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($p.Images[0].src)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
At D:\Data\Scripts\Cognos\TCDB_7-2.ps1:34 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest $imgSrc -WebSession $session | Select -ExpandProperty Content  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], UriFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: I tried completing the URL - but I get this message 
Set-Content : Cannot proceed with byte encoding. When using byte encoding the content must be of type byte.
At D:\Data\Scripts\Cognos\TCDB_7-2.ps1:35 char:83
+ ... erty Content | Set-Content -Encoding Byte $outPath
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

Comment: @uNoKaWaL After running your script, type this in the same PowerShell session: `Invoke-WebRequest $imgSrc -WebSession $session`  This will let you see the results of that request.  I suspect it is returning something other than the image and that may tell you why.

Comment: David The $imgSrc value is just this --<b_action=dc&amp;f=b3V0cHV0MzMyMTQ4NTc4MDI2MzI2MTA_&amp;k=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytE‌​txRbuihvYL-hHH4zZnTpCLtqVBxib4F09WKJAM_&amp;s=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-Qrg‌​F6CO4l*owSwzvuzgTNdf2khg_&amp;did=2013-03-21-08.24.10.711381>

Comment: even with the complete URL     (XYZ.com:12345/tarf/servlet/dispatch?b_action=dc&amp;f=b3V0cHV0MzMyMTQ4NTc4MDI2MzI2MTA_&amp;k=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytE‌​txRbuihvYL-hHH4zZnTpCLtqVBxib4F09WKJAM_&amp;s=FAAAAMoy9pBPf6OTheytEtxRbuihvYL-Qrg‌​F6CO4l*owSwzvuzgTNdf2khg_&amp;did=2013-03-21-08.24.10.711381)

I am unable to download/get the image.

With my initial script (using New-object -com internetexplorer.application) i am able t navigate to this and it shows me the image. i just can't download it.